# How to design publish-subscribe pattern properly in grpc?

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, grpc

i'm trying to implement pub sub pattern using grpc but i'm confusing a bit about how to do it properly.

my proto:  `rpc call (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream Data);`

client:

```
asynStub.call(Empty.getDefaultInstance(), new StreamObserver<Data>() {
         @Override
         public void onNext(Data value) {
           // process a data

         @Override
         public void onError(Throwable t) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onCompleted() {

         }
       });

   } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
     LOG.warn("RPC failed: {}", e.getStatus());
   }

   Thread.currentThread().join();
```

server service:

```
public class Sender extends DataServiceGrpc.DataServiceImplBase implements Runnable {
  private final BlockingQueue<Data> queue;
  private final static HashSet<StreamObserver<Data>> observers = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  public Sender(BlockingQueue<Data> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  @Override
  public void data(Empty request, StreamObserver<Data> responseObserver) {
    observers.add(responseObserver);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      try {
        // waiting for first element
        Data data = queue.take();
        // send head element
        observers.forEach(o -> o.onNext(data));

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOG.error("error: ", e);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to remove clients from global observers properly? How to received some sort of a signal when connection drops?
How to manage client-server reconnections? How to force client reconnect when connection drops?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the implementation of your service:

```java
  @Override
  public void data(Empty request, StreamObserver<Data> responseObserver) {
    observers.add(responseObserver);
  }
```

You need to get the [Context](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.19.0/context/src/main/java/io/grpc/Context.java#L180) of the current request, and [listen for cancellation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.19.0/context/src/main/java/io/grpc/Context.java#L460).  For single-request, multi-response calls (a.k.a. Server streaming) the gRPC generated code is simplified to pass in the the request directly.   This means that you con't have direct access to the underlying `ServerCall.Listener`, which is how you would normally listen for clients disconnecting and cancelling.

Instead, every gRPC call has a `Context` associated with it, which carries the cancellation and other request-scoped signals.  For your case, you just need to listen for cancellation by adding your own listener, which then safely removes the  response observer from your linked hash set.

---

As for reconnects:  gRPC clients will automatically reconnect if the connection is broken, but usually will not retry the RPC unless it is safe to do so.  In the case of server streaming RPCs, it is usually not safe to do, so you'll need to retry the RPC on your client directly.

Comment: Carl, thank you! Does it a good practice to build server streaming (pub/sub) on top of grpc?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Google's Cloud Pubsub is on top of gRPC, and their client source code is public on GitHub.  You can look at it for inspiration.